# Is this spelling with long ‘S’s correct?

Tags: orthographe, histoire, typographie

Is the following spelling containing long 'S's (used in Middle French) correct?
[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please provide the source where you found this

Comment: This is from Descartes' Discours de la méthode.

Comment: What makes you suspect it is incorrect?

Comment: @jlliagre because I don't speak a word of French (especially Middle French).

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think of this as [Middle French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_French) (which Wikipedia says ends in 1611, so a few decades before this sentence). Something like the *Pensées* by Pascal are IMO modern French except with antique ſpelling.

Comment: @ChrisW that's not the spelling that is ancient, just the typing.

Comment: @jlliagre I should have written, "antique type-ſetting", then.

Comment: Quelques détails [supplémentaires](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_long).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spelling is very correct. It didn't change since when this famous sentence was coined by Descartes in 1637 (later ***cogito ergo sum*** in 1644).

The typography matches what was used it that time. Only the final *S* has its current shape while the other ones are using the now obsolete [long variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s).

Comment: That is old fashioned typeface where the s looks like an f. Je pense donc je suis: I think therefore I am. In Latin, yes: Cogito ergo sum.