# Does savoir use a circumflex on the past participle su?

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe, participe-passé, diacritiques

I'm studying old baptism records where I frequently see the phrase, "qui n'ont su signer."

Sometimes it looks like this was spelled, "qui n'ont sû signer."

Is the circumflex just a variation of savoir?  Or more like a typo?

Comment: How old? It's possible that at that time, accents weren't standardized yet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a typo. Before being written ***[su](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/su)***, this past participle was written as ***sû*** or ***sü*** to remind the older spelling ***seu*** (along with ***sçu***, ***sceu*** and other).

[image]

Jean Le Jeune, *Le missionnaire de l'oratoire*, 1689

[image]

Jean de la Fontaine, *Le Magnifique*, 1685

It is similar to ***[mouvoir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mouvoir)*** that gave ***meu*** then ***mû*** and stayed that way until the 1990 recommendations allow to drop the circumflex and fix the inconsistency.

Comment: Cool ! Et pourquoi on écrivait le "s" pareil au "f" ("de fes voeux" et non "de ses voeux", "fes feux" pour "ses feux", "le furplus" pour "le surplus", etc.) ?

Comment: @ovide It is "l'esse longue" or ſ which was the original form of "s".

Comment: Thank you for the extra details.  I will add a follow up question soon, because I'm realizing a few instances that looked like "pu signer" might have been something more like "ſçu signer".  Surprise!

Comment: @ovide https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/is-this-spelling-with-long-s-s-correct

Comment: @ovide, the same [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) was used in English, as can be seen in the calligraphy in the file copy of the United States Bill of Rights recorded in 1789. Its first line is written “Congreſs of the United States.” Our modern lower-case *s* was used only as the final letter of words.

Comment: @ovide c'est discret, mais il y a bien une différence de graphie entre le f et s long. Le "f" a une barre horizontale à gauche et à droite. Le s long n'a une (petite) barre qu'à gauche.

Comment: @XouDo Merci beaucoup !

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Cool, merci !

Comment: @ovide, when I was a kid, I thought that the Bill of Rights started with some word *Congrels*, that rhymed with *mongrels*.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how old is the text, but it's more of a typography than anything else. Nowadays, circumflex accents tend to disappear.

Comment: They tend to desappear only when they are not mandatory. For example it is needed for `côte` to distinguish from `cote`, `dû` <> `du`, `tâche` <> `tache`, `pêcher` <> `pécher`...

Comment: @Toto Somehow French does manage to cope with pairs of words written the same with different meanings (with or without the same pronunciation): `fils`, `est`, `hélas`, `bus`, `car`, `or`, `son`, `as`, `plus`, etc. Given that, it's interesting that for a few pairs, disambiguation via a circumflex is still "mandatory" even when the circumflex is tending to disappear elsewhere.