# Distinguishing "pu" and "ſcu" in cursive

Tags: orthographe

Example 1:

[image: Example 1]
[image]

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]
[image]

Example 3:

[image: Example 3]
[image]

Until today, I thought this phrase was, "qui n'ont pu signer".

After I saw the new answer about [Savoir with Circumflex](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53942/savoir-with-circumflex/53945), I wondered if this could be transcribed as "qui n'ont ſcu signer" or "qui n'ont ſsu signer"?

Examples updated with nearby instances of "paroisse" or "paroiſse" in the same hand.

Comment: Il y a un vieux "s" qui ressemble à un "f", mais il y a un "pont" de trop pour que ce soit ce "s/f" à mon avis. Il faudrait voir d'autres exemples de "p" de la même main.

Comment: @Frank Question updated.

Comment: Hmmm. But in the case of "paroisse", there are clearly 2 "s", the first apparently using that old "f" typography, the second loop clearly being the second "s". In the case of "pu/su", there would be only one "s" involved, so the similarity with "paroi**ss**e" IMHO breaks down. Also, in this handwriting, the "s" seems to be pointy at the top, whereas the initial "p" of "paroisse" is more rounded? I would gravitate towards "**p**u signer".

Comment: @Frank I see now the need for context clues.  Feel free to post the answer.

Comment: Do you have the date of that text?

Comment: *Savoir, c'est pouvoir !* ;-)

Comment: Roughly 1800 to 1900.  I can get the exact dates if it helps.

Comment: I'm not really a specialist, dates were just to have an idea if it was really old (1600?) or more recent (1800+). We have a school in France that trains specialists: https://www.chartes.psl.eu/.

Comment: @RobertChapin do you see a pattern of using the old S at the beginning of words in the rest of the text or is it the only occurrence?

Comment: @guillaume31 I think it is not at the beginning of words.  That might be the best clue.  In example 3, the p and the long s look almost identical.

Comment: @RobertChapin yes, this and Frank's point about the small loop being a *second* S if there ever was an S converge towards "pu", I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at other examples of "p" and "s" in the text, it seems that in the case of "paroisse", there are clearly 2 "s", the first apparently using an old "f" typography, the second loop clearly being the second "s". But in the case of "pu/su", there would be only one "s" involved, so the similarity with the "s" in "paroisse" IMHO breaks down. Also, in this handwriting, the "s" seems to be pointy at the top, whereas the initial "p" of "paroisse" seems to be more rounded. I would thus gravitate towards "pu signer", rather than "su signer".

Comment: Writing double s as long followed by short s in this way was standard: see https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Blog/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html. I agree though that this reads to me as "pu" rather than "su".

Comment: If you trace a double "s" and a "p" in cursive, the "s" tends to be more pointy, the "p" more round, something that seems apparent in all 3 examples of "pu".